# Spatial join QGIS, finding the number of points within a radius of another point

Tags: qgis, distance, attribute-joins

I am very new to QGIS and am pulling my hair out trying to find a solution to my problem:

I have two very large tables that I have plotted in different layers within my workspace, the first of which is the location of property sales and the second being short term rentals.

What I'm trying to achieve is to somehow find how many points in the rental layer lie within a radius of say 200 meters from the points in the sales layer at the time of sale.

I have dates for both of these in the tables.

Ideally I would then like to add a column into my sales table to say that there are "x" number of rental properties nearby when the property is sold.

I'm guessing that this can be achieved by some form of spatial join function but I am really struggling to achieve this given the time restriction that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: This is not a full answer to your question, but I suspect you're either going to have to split up your sales and rental data into layers representing discrete time chunks, which will be awkward, or start poking around with QGIS' spatiotemporal extensions. It looks like the QGIS Time Manager (http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/time%20manager/) would be a good place to start.

Comment: What if you buffer the sales layer points and create the spatial join? Of course, there is the possibility that a rental point might fall in more than one circle.